# Unity - Navigation mash doesn't appear

Tags: unity-game-engine, navigation

I'm trying to add a navigation mash to my unity project, I'm following a tutorial, as I'm new in it, but i stacked at this point.

I'm following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fuHFrMZ4q_s&t=610s)  from youtube. For some reason I can't follow after navigation added, as it doesn't appear on the screen.

After some googling, (for me) everything looks fine. Maybe it is, maybe not, it's just me, who desn't see. Anyway: I've made a [VIDEO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CuVCC006QgI) on my computer, to show, that everything looks OK(ish).

Thank you, if you have any idea!

Answer (score 0):

See if this is checked when the navigation window is opened.
[image]

Otherwise restarting Unity might fix the problem.